# Does a std::allocator need to be default constructible?

Tags: c++, containers, c++17, std, allocator

If I'm not missing something, according to the [requirements of *Allocator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator), the `Allocator`template argument of a `std::vector` doesn't need to be default constructible.

However, the following [minimal example doesn't compile (LIVE demo)](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=4339328ebd905617):

```
#include <vector>


template<typename T>
class stateful_allocator
{
public:
    using value_type = T;

    constexpr explicit stateful_allocator(int s) noexcept
        : m_state(s)
    {}

    template <typename U>
    stateful_allocator(stateful_allocator<U> const& other) noexcept {
        m_state = other.m_state;
    }

    T* allocate(std::size_t) { return nullptr; }
    void deallocate(T*, std::size_t) noexcept {}

private:
    int m_state;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
bool operator==(stateful_allocator<T> const&, stateful_allocator<U> const&) noexcept {
    return true;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
bool operator!=(stateful_allocator<T> const& x, stateful_allocator<U> const& y) noexcept {
    return !(x == y);
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int, stateful_allocator<int>> x(0);
}
```

Comment: Seems like it is missing a bunch of type declarations.

Answer (score 4):

`std::vector<int, stateful_allocator<int>> x(0)` is calling the `std::vector` constructor overload which takes a size, not implicitly converting `0` to `stateful_allocator` (which you've disallowed anyway by marking your constructor `explicit`).

As you aren't passing in an allocator instance one is default constructed due to the default arguments in the constructor.

Try:

```
std::vector<int, stateful_allocator<int>> x(stateful_allocator<int>{0});
```